# Name doesn't exist in current context error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This question has been asked in the past but the fixes weren't working for me, so sorry in advance for reposting.  I put in **'s the MenuItems references I am getting errors on.  It is really strange since I reference MenuItems here numerous times and I don't get the error.

```
      public ActionResult AddMenuItems(List<int> MenuItemID)
    {


    //  Need to run through array of MEnuItem ID's and add them to the Followers LIst of MEnuItems
        Follower follower = db.Followers.Find(FollowerID);//Added a property stub hope it makes it work
        // Remove deselected menu items
        follower.MenuItems.Where(m => **!MenuItemId**.Contains(m.MenuItemID)).ToList()
            .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Remove(m));

        // Add newly selected menu items
        var existingMenuItemIds = follower.MenuItems.Select(m => m.MenuItemID).ToList();
        db.MenuItems.Where(m => **MenuItemIds**.Except(existingMenuItemIds).Contains(m.MenuItemID)).ToList()
            .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Add(m));

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `**!MenuItemId**` is `MenuItemID`?

Comment: I am new to C# and was under the impression that !MenuItemID translated to "not MenuItemID"

Comment: I mean `MenuItemId` and `MenuItemID` are two different literals. C# is case sensitive language. You should be using `MenuItemID` rather than `MenuItemId` which is why you're getting errors.

Comment: Oh wow, I stared at that forever, those little mistakes, helps to have that extra set of eyes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MenuItemId and MenuItemID are two different literals. C# is case sensitive language. You should be using MenuItemID rather than MenuItemId which is why you're getting errors.